# NCrunch test fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: ncrunch

My test requires an NHibernate configuration file. The file is added through NCrunch configuration:
[image]

But the test still fails with:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: NHibernate configuration file not found.
File name: 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\NCrunch\9176\20\_ncrunchreferences.
```

Is there any way to force files being added to `_ncrunchreferences` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue with a help of [`Copy Referenced Assemblies To Workspace`](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/considerations-and-constraints_assembly-colocation-assumptions) option. Might need to clean NCrunch cache for this to take effect.

Other options to the problem would possibly be using a pre-build event to copy needed resources over (`Run pre-build events` option has to be enabled in NCrunch project configuration).